# How to set Qt style to default?

Tags: qt, gui-toolkits

I installed Telegram messenger from `ppa:atareao/telegram` (Source: [Web Upd8)](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/install-official-telegram-desktop-app.html).

Telegram messenger is a Qt app. elementary OS seem to set the Qt style to Windows instead of default. This results in the Telegram messenger dialog window not using the QtCreator but the Windows dialog.

This is the windows dialog:

[image: Windows dialog]

This is the Qt Dialog that I want to use:

[image: Qt Dialog]

The issue is described in more detail there:

- Make tdesktop look native / Do not set Qt style to win by default [#987](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/987)
- Can the Linux client use GTK FileChooser? [#982](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/982#issue-99888421)

**My question to the community is the following:**

How do I configure my elementary OS setup to make Telegram use the Qt Dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did for change the Qt apps style is add this line:

> QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk

In the environment file:

> gedit /etc/environment

Then reboot the system.

This is how Focus Writer looks like in my system:
[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work with FocusWriter. Could you test FocusWriter yourself and please confirm that your answer integrates FocusWriter properly? Thanks!

Comment: I've attached a pic of how FocusWriter looks like in my system, is this the style you want?

Comment: Yes, that's how I want it to be! I notice that you have a spelling mistake in your answer regarding `/etc/environtment`.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through this bug report.

[qtgtk style cannot detect elementary gtk style](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1074721)

There are fixes mentioned in this report.

The first being(for x86_64):

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme Elementary
```

And for 32bit applications on x86_64:

Install ia32-libs

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) ia32-libs is no longer included in the os.

Since Ubuntu 11.10 [Multiarch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) has been added.

Anyway, to explicitly install `ia32-libs`:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr) you can also try installing 32bit library of the application:

```
apt-get install program:i386
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give some examples of application-specific ia32-libs packages?

Comment: ia32-libs helps getting 32bit packages installed on 64bit machine. This hack has become quite old now and is not being used since Ubuntu 11.10. Multiarch is being used now. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you give any explanation for adding this specific repository? `raring` is not the Ubuntu version Freya is based on. Moreover, `raring` is discontinued (as it's on `old-releases.ubuntu.com`).  Your answer sounds dangerous to users and I don't see any sense in adding the `raring` repository. As said in your link about ia32-libs, it's an obsolete concept and shouldn't be used anymore. Please don't tell people how to do things wrong.

Comment: I like writing detailed answers, providing every possible way to solve a problem. I'm sorry if you find this answer dangerous. I know elementary freya is not based on ubuntu 11 and if you read my answer as well as the comments, you will see that i have mentioned that the process of using ia32-libs is old now and that it has been replaced with Multiarch. I also provided links that explains things in details so that before using what i wrote, people can choose which method they want to solve a particular problem. But what you said, i will surely keep this in mind.

Comment: @godslayer_69 I tried your proposed solution for x86_64 but it does not change the design with respect to FocusWriter. Could you test FocusWriter yourself and report back whether your solution works for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI after this bug/request was filed for Loki beta2 (or nearly-RC1): https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1616838 it appears to have been addressed here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/default-settings-loki/revision/207

While this does seem to help with the look and feel, not sure how/if it helps with the file dialog issue, maybe that's more work.